# object oriented matrix multiplication using multithreading

Tags: java, oop, matrix

I am in need of designing a multi-threaded matrix multiplication using OO principles. Below is the outline of the classes i came up with.

```
class matrix{

}


class matrixThread implements runnable{

}
```

the matrix class will hold the actual matrix. In this application there needs to be 3 matrices so i have to create three of them. And i need to multiply them using 4 threads.So i create 4 matrixThread  objects and invoke the .start method with the actual matrix multiplication code inside the run method.

Could someone please comment on my approach. Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: I would research the implementations which have been done already. What are you trying to do which is different?

Comment: i researched but found none. Could someone please help me.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+matrix+multiplication+fork+join 2.5 million hits.

Comment: yeah i know, i was asking whether my Object oriented approach is correct or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should be to copy a solution which works already. Matrix multiplication is a well understood problem and getting the best performance (which makes using multiple threads worth doing) is a bit tricky and you will save yourself some grief by just using an existing solution.  If you just try something which should work, you can find it is slower than using one thread if you do not test  carefully. (As you need to be careful as to the number of threads you create and how the caches are used)

Comment: yes, but i am wanting a object oriented version of it. Why doesn't anyone get what i say :( ?

Comment: Because all the implementations use object orientated programming. You may as well say you want to use code. Can you say how your requirements differ from those available and why you need those differences?